# Android Show Progress Bar on the top of video

Tags: android, video, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Right now, the progress bar is showing at the center of the screen.
So the user needs to wait till the download progress is done because the 
entire screen is un-work-able.
I would like to show the progress bar while the video is downloaded (refer image).

[image]

So the Part A is video Part. While the video is downloading,
i would like to allowed user to work on Part B.

Current code, im calling the ProgressDialog on onPreExcute method inside AsyncTask

```
 protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
        }
```

And dissmiss the dialog at onPostExecute

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after the file was downloaded
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this :-

first declare your videoview inside a relative-layout in XML

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/videoLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/channel_icon_small"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp4_space"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8_margin" >


            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/videoView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp8_margin" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

then u can add a ProgressBar dynamically :-

```
ProgressBar mProgressBar = new ProgressBar(this);
        mProgressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mProgressBar.setEnabled(true);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lProgressBarLayoutParms = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lProgressBarLayoutParms.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        mProgressBar.setLayoutParams(lProgressBarLayoutParms);
        mVideoLayout.addView(mProgressBar);
```

you can use following code in `onPreExecute()` method of AsyncTask and then hide the progressbar in `onPostExecute()` method